Why is the flutter app.release.apk not present?? It's not present in /outputs/flutterapk
You know how when we run the flutter app (using flutter run), after running, the app will stay on our device right? i think that's because of the release-apk being installed. But in my case, when i stop running, and close the app, it's not present in my phone at all.
When i go to app/outputs/flutterapks/ There's only:

app-debug.apk
app-debug.apk.sha1

There should be app-release.apk too right? Its not present. What do i do?
This is what i get for running flutter build apk :

Font asset "CupertinoIcons.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 257628 to 836 bytes (99.7% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 1716 bytes (99.9% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c683cde5b1f5377825fe27da54e1b718/transformed/fragment-1.7.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/fragment_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4b07bb875192e8c29c9b76677237c5c8/transformed/jetified-activity-1.8.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/activity_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/455c428e62a6dd75da98c7152f7af462/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx-2.7.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/
lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0313b4099446464f98d0df0606c58c95/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-2.7.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.     
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2e94595ca22e3aadcdebdc547820608c/transformed/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.7.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.   
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ce9e6112a0f9c5113844bb49506e7a06/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.7.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-liv
edata-core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6e7c2231d2ac9b957ecfe9d432e59ed2/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-2.7.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-I
NF/lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/740c93e8e1043856a6b7cb15a7eaa9f0/transformed/jetified-core-ktx-1.13.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/fac84cd5ecf1ec88a8c98571217c9350/transformed/core-1.13.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/98474e5913354eaede53aaa879a4dd8b/transformed/lifecycle-runtime-2.7.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.       
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d674cd90e13def17f77b3f8010d35e09/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-process-2.7.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-
process_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.7.0/85334205d65cca70ed0109c3acbd29e22a2d9cb1/lifecycle-common-2.7.0.ja
r!/META-INF/lifecycle-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/5292c4072ce6d2ab49b0e25db445cdfe/transformed/jetified-window-java-1.2.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/window-java_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d47b1192960df52846144d82ac9e1d6f/transformed/jetified-window-1.2.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/window_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm/1.7.1/63a0779cf668e2a47d13fda7c3b0c4f8dc7762f4/kotlinx-cor
outines-core-jvm-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-android/1.7.1/c2d86b569f10b7fc7e28d3f50c0eed97897d77a7/kotlinx-coro
utines-android-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-android.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/aadceac8ee0316c01a9163bad1a5e0ed/transformed/jetified-savedstate-1.2.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!
/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!
/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!
/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.8.22/1a8e3601703ae14bb58757ea6b2d8e8e5935a586/kotlin-stdlib-comm
on-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           88.0s


I want the release apk, How do i solve this?
Or is there something like, the release-apk will only be generated after running flutter build apk ??

Did you wait long enough ? Your logs seem unfinished it should show you the output path at the end

If you want to run the app in release mode, you should use flutter run --release command.

As @imGok mentioned, the output you've shared is still a running command (flutter build apk). Please wait for it to finish and you will see the whole path of the release apk once it is generated.
Example output
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           27.4s
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk (19.0MB).

